# What is an example of the "good tidings" brought by Islamic messengers?

Tags: tafseer, messengers, surat-al-anam

This question relates to the verse:

> And **We send not the messengers except as bringers of good tidings** and warners. So whoever believes and reforms - there will be no fear concerning them, nor will they grieve.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 6:48](https://quran.com/6/48)</sub>

It's easy to find examples of warnings in the Qur'an, but I'm wondering about these "good tidings".

**Question**: What is an example of the "good tidings" brought by Islamic messengers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just as easy to find examples of the 'good tidings' as well. More so, actually :)

The most prominent example of good tidings that Prophets preached is the **promise of Paradise** for those who do good. The Qur'an itself gives this good tiding and it is mentioned throughout.

> إن هذا القرآن يهدي للتي هي أقوم ويبشر المؤمنين الذين يعملون الصالحات أن لهم أجرا كبيرا (Indeed, this Qur'an guides to that which is most suitable and gives good tidings to the believers who do righteous deeds that they will have a great reward) - Qur'an 17:9.

Good tidings can also be regarding events in the future in this Dunya. One great example is when 'Isa (peace be upon him) brought the great news of the next (final) promised Messenger.

> وإذ قال عيسى ابن مريم يا بني إسرائيل إني رسول الله إليكم مصدقا لما بين يدي من التوراة ومبشرا برسول يأتي من بعدي اسمه أحمد فلما جاءهم بالبينات قالوا هذا سحر مبين (And [mention] when Jesus, the son of Mary, said, "O children of Israel, indeed I am the messenger of Allah to you confirming what came before me of the Torah and bringing good tidings of a messenger to come after me, whose name is Ahmad." But when he came to them with clear evidences, they said, "This is obvious magic.") - Qur'an 61:6.

There are other examples as well throughout the Qur'an, such as the Angels bringing good tidings about patient or righteous figures in the Qur'an being granted offspring (eg, 'Isa, Ya'qub, etc.. - peace be upon them).